# “Ambiguous column name” error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error

> Additional information: Ambiguous column name 'WeekNo'

I get this error after I added this SQL to my query:

```
JOIN 
    sip.StudentJournalDate sjd ON sjd.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo 
                               AND sjd.AdminNo = sj.AdminNo 
                               AND sjd.ProjectId = sj.ProjectId
```

Complete query:

```
SELECT
    sj.LOComment,      
    CONVERT(varchar, sjd.StartDateEntry,103) WeekStartDate,
    CONVERT(varchar, sjd.EndDateEntry,103) WeekEndDate,
    supervisor.SupervisorEmails,
    LO.LOEmails,
    sj.AdminNo,
    sj.AcadYear, 
    sj.WeekNo, 
    sj.StartDateEntry,                         
    sj.Day1Journal, sj.Day2Journal, sj.Day3Journal, sj.Day4Journal, sj.Day5Journal, sj.Day6Journal, sj.Day7Journal, 
    sj.WeeklyReflection, 
    sj.Day1TypeOfLeaveCode, sj.Day2TypeOfLeaveCode, sj.Day3TypeOfLeaveCode, 
    sj.Day4TypeOfLeaveCode, sj.Day5TypeOfLeaveCode, sj.Day6TypeOfLeaveCode, 
    sj.Day7TypeOfLeaveCode, 
    sj.ProjectId, sj.coursesiprunid
FROM  
    sip.StudentJournal sj 
JOIN 
    sip.StudentJournalDate sjd ON sjd.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo 
                               AND sjd.AdminNo = sj.AdminNo 
                               AND sjd.ProjectId = sj.ProjectId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT  
          adminno, projectId, coursesiprunid,
          STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(EmailAddress AS VARCHAR(320)) [text()]
                 FROM sip.ApplicationProjectLO a
                 INNER JOIN V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa ON a.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID
                 WHERE adminno = t.adminno
                   AND a.type IN ('L','A')
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ' ') LOEmails
      FROM 
          sip.ApplicationProjectLO t
      GROUP BY 
          adminno, projectId, coursesiprunid) Lo ON sj.AdminNo = Lo.AdminNo 
                                                 AND sj.CourseSIPRunId = Lo.CourseSIPRunId
                                                 AND sj.projectid = Lo.ProjectId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT  
         adminno, projectId, coursesiprunid,
         STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(vsa.StaffEmail AS VARCHAR(320)) [text()]
                FROM sip.ApplicationProjectSupervisor  a
                INNER JOIN sip.CompanyStaff vsa ON a.CompanyStaffId = vsa.CompanyStaffId
                WHERE adminno = t.adminno
                  AND a.type IN ('S', 'MR')
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ' ') SupervisorEmails
     FROM 
         sip.ApplicationProjectSupervisor t
     GROUP BY 
         adminno, projectId, coursesiprunid) Supervisor ON sj.AdminNo = Supervisor.adminno
                                                        AND sj.CourseSIPRunId =Supervisor.CourseSIPRunId
                                                        AND sj.projectid = Supervisor.ProjectId
WHERE
    sj.AdminNo = @adminno 
    AND sj.CourseSIPRunId = @coursesiprunid
    AND sj.projectid = @projectId
    AND WeekNo = @weekNo";
```

Comment: and WeekNo = @weekNo";  there is no alias on WeekNo here

Comment: You have to specify which weekno in the WHERE clause's `WeekNo = @weekNo`.

Comment: Ok. solved. Didn't notice it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You have not mention alias. alias.WeekNO = @WeekNo.

```
WHERE
    sj.AdminNo = @adminno 
    AND sj.CourseSIPRunId = @coursesiprunid
    AND sj.projectid = @projectId
    AND sj.WeekNo = @weekNo";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give an example.When two of people in room are with same name (user3807187) then when someone calls by the same name then both of you gets confused. This is what happening with your code. For this what you can do is both of them can be temporarily renamed with addition of your surname with name then both of you when called by your aliase name can be cleared. The same is required for the database. When two tables has same colume name then when you select the field you append table name with its column name to clear ambiguity.

you need to place alias for column without alias name like

```
WHERE tablename.adminno = t.adminno
```

likewise for all ambigious name field (CourseSIPRunId ,..)